# How to measure $V \propto I^3$ behavior of $\text{NbSe}_2$ under its critical current?

Tags: experimental-physics, superconductivity, experimental-technique

Last week, I attempted to measure the superconductivity of multilayer NbSe${}_2$.
As one can see in figure 4 in [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-017-00427-5), I expected $V \propto I^3 $ behavior under its critical current $I_c$ for its $V\text{-}I$ characteristic curve.
However, immersed in a cryostat of 1.4 Kelvin with a superconducting magnet, my sample only showed an Ohmic behavior:$V\propto I$ strict line rather than $V\propto I^3$ curve.
How can I observe the $I^3$ curve from my device?

My device was a multilayer NbSe${}_2$ exfoliated from bulk flakes. Then I deposited it on a silicon substrate and coated it with the PMMA. After patterning with a scanning electron microscope, I added thin layers of Cr, Pd, Au in order. Lifted off sample has its geometry as:[image: sample]

Note that the left-hand side of electrode 2 is a junction, meaning that its height is different from the main body. I used 2 as a drain and 1 as a source. I measured voltage drop between electrode 3 and 4 and current with lock-in amplifiers.

In addition to strict Ohmic behavior, my lock-in amplifier was too noisy. I am having doubt about contacts between electrodes and silicon substrate may cause problem but not sure.